# Argand Diagram confusion

Tags: complex-numbers

While searching on net about Argand diagram or complex plane we get images of both kinds which have their $y-$axis either real axis or imaginary axis.

Given $z = x + yi$, some people write $Im(z) = y$ and other $Im(z) = yi$,

So what is the TRUTH which comply with diagram as well.

From my knowledge of mathematica I know that there is no special complex plane, Wolfram has 'programmed' to include complex number.

Thnx.

Comment: The imaginary part is defined as $y$, not $iy$. It is a much more useful definition this way. For example, one can say "The magnitude of a complex number is the square root of the sum of squares of its real and imaginary parts". http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ImaginaryPart.html

Comment: look the mathworld. I(z) contains i. Why?

Comment: No, check carefully. First, they have defined $\Im[x + iy] = y$. Then they have given a *formula* for it in terms of $z$ and its conjugate $\bar{z}$. If $z = x + iy$, then the conjugate is $\bar{z} = x - iy$. From this, we get $\Re(z) = \dfrac{z + \bar{z}}{2}$, and $\Im(z) = \dfrac{z - \bar{z}}{2i}$. The $i$ in the denominator ensures that the $i$ in the numerator gets cancelled out, so you always get a real number.

Answer (score 2):

The imaginary part of the complex number $z = x+yi$ is $y$ not $yi$, and we sometimes write $\operatorname{Im}(z) = y$. Likewise, we write $\operatorname{Re}(z) = x$ for the real part of $x$

On an Argand diagram, the horizontal axis is the real part, and the vertical axis is the imaginary part and should be labelled $\operatorname{Re}(z)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(z)$ respectively, although some people choose to supress the $z$ and just use $\operatorname{Re}$ and $\operatorname{Im}$.

Comment: Thnks. U may find images showing numbers along y-axis as i, 2i, 3i, 4i,... Is it wrong?

Comment: I don't know if it is necessarily wrong, but I think it is uncommon.

Comment: @user156842 As far as the markings on the axis are concerned, you can think of it as unit markings. For example, when the scale of each axis is mentioned explicitly in a graph (say, one is in seconds and the other is in meters), there is no need to again mark the axes with $1$m, $2$m, etc. and $1$s, $2$s, etc. Whereas if the scale is not mentioned, the axes themselves will include the units in the markings. In the Argand diagram too, the $y$-axis may be marked with $i$, $2i$, etc. specifically, but usually this is assumed and understood, so there is no need to do so.

Comment: @user156842 However, independent of how the axis is marked, the imaginary part of a complex number is always defined the same way.